# SQL query suggestion for horizontal wise row union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A table Family is like

```
No.  ADD  Member  Det1  Det2  Det3  Det4

1    Add1  Dad1    q     w     e     r
1    Add1  Mom1    q     w     e     r
1    Add1  Chd1    q     w     e     r
1    Add1  Chd1    q     w     e     r
1    Add2  Mom2    q     w     e     r
1    Add2  Chd2    q     w     e     r
1    Add2  Chd2    q     w     e     r
```

*ADD* here is like family ID unique per family, *Member* is name of member and family can have any number members.

Desired output:

```
No.  ADD  Member  Det1  Det2  Det3  Det4  Member  Det1  Det2  Det3  Det4 .. more
1    Add1 Dad1    q     w     e     r     Mom1    q     w     e     r    .. more
2    Add2 Mom2    q     w     e     r     Chd1    q     w     e     r    .. more
```

I tried with creating alias to number of member

```
SELECT a.ADD
    ,a.Member
    ,a.Det1
    ,a.Det2
    ,a.Det3
    ,a.Det4
    ,b.bDD
    ,b.Member
    ,b.Det1
    ,b.Det2
    ,b.Det3
    ,b.Det4
FROM Family a
    ,Family b
WHERE a.ADD = b.ADD
```

Comment: I think a pivot would be better for what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you are trying to do is called PIVOTing a query. But your case is a little bit difficult because, if I understand, you want to mount your resultset in a two columns. And your desired result do not fit with the registries you provide as example.

Comment: What you need here is a dynamic cross tab. A pivot won't work because you have multiple aggregates. Take a look at this article which explains how to build this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: @JorgeCampos isn't pivoting is converting row to column name which is not required here. Can you give an idea on how to solve using pivoting.

Comment: What are you using to consume the output of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: 11:26 PST.  I think you need dynamic SQL to do what you want.  As you are doing a complex block set that you are adding on column wise and repeating the column names as well.**

```
declare @Temp table ( [No] int, [Add] varchar(4), Member varchar(4), Det1 char, Det2 char, Det3 char, Det4 char);

insert into @Temp values
(1,    'Add1', 'Dad1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Mom1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Chd1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Chd1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Mom2', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Chd2', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Chd2', 'q','w','e','r')


if object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null
    drop table #temp

select 
    No
,  [Add]
,  Member
,  Det1
,  Det2
,  Det3
,  Det4
,  dense_rank() over(order by [Add]) as part
,  row_number() over(partition by [Add] order by Member) as rwn

into #Temp
from @Temp

declare 
    @Cursor int = 1
,   @Max int

,   @Addendum varchar(max) = ''
,   @NL char = char(10)
,   @SQL nvarchar(max) 
,   @Part int
;

-- set up my loop prep

-- statement to execute later
select @SQL = 'Select No, [Add] ' + @NL + 'from #Temp' + @NL + 'group by No, [Add]';

-- max iteration of an occurence
Select @Max = max(rwn) from #Temp 

-- ensure we use the part that has the max occurrence, less we get less results than we need
Select @Part = max(part) from #Temp where rwn = @Max

-- While the statement is looping it is adding to itself dynamically to select your values.  I could do a loop of a loop 
-- to get only certain values you want too, but this is enough for an example.  EG, set a bit for Det1, Det2 and then make a statement for those things too.
While @Cursor <= @Max
BEGIN
    Select @Addendum += @NL + ', max(case when rwn = ' + cast(@Cursor as varchar) + ' then Member end) as Member ' +
        @NL + ', max(case when rwn = ' + cast(@Cursor as varchar) + ' then Det1 end) as Det1 ' +
        @NL + ', max(case when rwn = ' + cast(@Cursor as varchar) + ' then Det2 end) as Det2 ' +
        @NL + ', max(case when rwn = ' + cast(@Cursor as varchar) + ' then Det3 end) as Det3 ' +
        @NL + ', max(case when rwn = ' + cast(@Cursor as varchar) + ' then Det4 end) as Det4 '
    from #Temp where part = @Part and rwn = @Cursor

    Select @Cursor += 1;

END

-- 'stuff' is a sql syntax to insert in a specific place a chunk of something.
Select @SQL = stuff(@SQL, charindex('from', @SQL), 0,  @Addendum + @NL);

-- I want to now 'execute' the statement I just built up in memory to select what I need
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

It looks like you are simply doing a complex grouping but I am unsure from your example if you are wanting to explicitly leave out some of your members.  This will run as is on SQL Server 2008 and higher as is:

```
declare @Temp table ( [No] int, [Add] varchar(4), Member varchar(4), Det1 char, Det2 char, Det3 char, Det4 char);

insert into @Temp values
(1,    'Add1', 'Dad1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Mom1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Chd1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add1', 'Chd1', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Mom2', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Chd2', 'q','w','e','r'),
(1,    'Add2', 'Chd2', 'q','w','e','r')

Select *
from @Temp

select 
    No
,   [Add]
,   Member
,   max(Det1) as Det1
,   max(Det2) as Det2
,   max(Det3) as Det3
,   max(Det4) as Det4
from @Temp
group by No, [Add], Member
```

A 'Pivot' procedure is good for taking a set of values that is commonly associated with a single 'type' value.  This is good for things that are multi rows for lookup values.

Like you have a person and they are linked to an order table and the order table has a type column that is related to a lookup table that is a key pair table like

1 = shirt, 2 = pants, 3 = shoes, 4 = socks, 5 = belt, 6 = hat, 7 = watch, etc..

You can commonly do a pivot for a few things by simple doing a left join and expressining the 'type' you want to pivot off of.  EG:

```
from person p
left join order o1 on p.personid = o1.personid and o1.type = 1
left join order o2 on p.personid = o2.personid and o2.type = 2
```

There is no rule in the engine that states you can only join a table once only so if I specify you join on relationship AND specifically a certain type, I can evaluate my select like so:

```
 Select p.PersonName, o1.Value, o2.Value
```

Typically Pivot is used when you have a whole bunch of types and you don't want to do multiple left joins.  When you are doing a set of sequences you want to group by, you really only need to do a 'group by' for simple sets.  I could do this by:

1. a standard group by listed above where each column in the 'group by' is controlling the flow and then doing an aggregate('max' used above) to find ONLY a single value of the maximum occurence of that grouping.  Provided your No, Add, and Member will have a single value represented this works.
2. a max(case when then end) statement which does the grouping for me in the expression like below:

   Select 
       y.PersonName
   ,   max(case when OrderID = 1 then OrderAmount end) 
   ,   max(case when OrderID = 2 then OrderAmount end) 
   ,   max(case when OrderID = 3 then OrderAmount end) 
   from @Person y
       join @Orders x on x.PersonId = y.PersonId
   group by PersonName
3. Windowed functions that give me dynamic grouping abilities without a 'group by' clause.

   Select
       y.PersonName
   ,   OrderAmount
   ,   row_number() over(partition by PersonName order by OrderAmount) orderbyAmount
   ,   row_number() over(partition by PersonName order by OrderAmount desc) orderbyAmountDesc
   ,   max(case when OrderID = 1 then OrderAmount end) over(partition by PersonName)

   ,   max(case when OrderID = 2 then OrderAmount end) over(partition by PersonName)
   ,   max(case when OrderID = 3 then OrderAmount end) over(partition by PersonName)
   from @Person y
       join @Orders x on x.PersonId = y.PersonId

This gives me flexibility if someone wants some crazy report that lists the 2nd or last occurence of something by a complicated process.

Comment: @djangojazz No, all members in family  should come in same row without *No* and *ADD* column repeating.

Comment: @Conrad, I missed that.  I would use dynamic SQL in this case with windowed functions.  There may be a more elegant way to do this but you need to account for if the members are more for one grouping than another.  Update coming...